# Get width and height of scaled down image after imagerotation?

Tags: php, rotation, gd

A followup to this question:
[How to get new width and height after an image has been rotated with imagerotate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762132/how-to-get-new-width-and-height-after-an-image-has-been-rotated-with-imagerotate)

The answer I got is based on the filenames actual image size, but if I want to start from another width and height.

How would I achieve that? See below code for my attempt...

```
$ps['product_angle'] = 77; //Could be any angle
$filename = 'test.png'     //filename to the original product

list($source_width, $source_height) = getimagesize($filename);
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 

//Example for clarification (this is parameters that is used to save new image)
$ps['product_width'] = 40;      //for example $source_width = 200
$ps['product_height'] = 80;     //and $source_height = 400


$angle = $ps['product_angle'];
if (intval($angle) <> 0) {

   //Actual dimensions of image from filename
    $current_source_x = imagesx($source_image); 
    $current_source_y = imagesy($source_image);

    //Get current ratio of "scaled down image"
    $ratio_x = $ps['product_width'] / $current_source_x;
    $ratio_y = $ps['product_height'] / $current_source_y;

    $source_image = imagerotate( 
        $source_image, 
        360-$angle, 
        imageColorAllocateAlpha($source_image, 255, 255, 255, 127)
    );

   //New dimensions from actual filename
   //This would be fine if I just wanted the new width and height
   //based on the filenames dimension, but I want new dimensions
   //for the "scaled downed version" of the image (40, 80)
   $new_image_source_x = imagesx($source_image);
   $new_image_source_y = imagesy($source_image);

   //I tried this, but obviously I'm doing something totally wrong        
   $new_width = ($new_image_source_x - $current_source_x)  * $ratio_x;
   $new_height = ($new_image_source_y - $current_source_y)  * $ratio_y;

   //Set new width after rotation                                                    
   $ps['product_width']  = $new_width;
   $ps['product_height'] = $new_height;


}

$ps['source_image'] = $source_image;
list($source_width, $source_height) =     getimagesize($filename);

$dest_width = (int)$ps['product_width']; 
$dest_height = (int)$ps['product_height'];

//Resize source-image to new width and height
//
imagecopyresized($dest_image, $ps['source_image'], 0, 0, 0, 0, $dest_width, $dest_height, $source_width, $source_height);
```

Probably I'm missing something very essential....

**UPDATE**

An example of real values...

```
image current width63.224619257754
image current height80.210337864315

//after calculation
image new width37.583523669887
image newt height21.716336015666

where angle is 41.10419020401479
```

Comment: Please add details to your question: What is the error, what values do you get?

Comment: I've updated my question because I hade some copy and paste errors, but besides that - I don't get expected width and height ($new_width and $new_height).

Comment: new width and height gets far to small. Look at update

Comment: If you look at the new image, is there some content missing? Is it cut off?

Comment: If you turn it 77° the image must be bigger than before so every pixel is not lost. if you turn it 90° width and height just change its places. Basically you have to adjust jour height by using sin / cos, that's where i am out sticking time into it, maybe someone else likes to solve this for you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I guess that would move me forward in right direction anyway :-)

Comment: Okay, if it is cut off, then it is smaller to fit a full rectangle... (insert bill and ted meme here)

Comment: I've actually came into a solution. I will post when I have som more time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my comment

> "I've actually came into a solution"

.. It wasn't the day when I used my best english skills...

**I guess you know what I meant though and here is how I solved my issue:**

In my approach I was trying to calculate the new values based on ratio from the "scaled down image" and then get new width and height based on the difference from the "scaled down image" and "the image after rotated".

Something like this:

1. Set the relation/ratio between "scaled down image" and original image.
2. Do the actual image-rotation
3. Get the difference between original dimensions from the rotated image and multiply that with ratio-factor set before image was rotated.
4. Get the new width and height based on the rotation angle

This really didn't work correctly (failed at **step4**). I've been looking around a lot to find answers how to calculate width and height after an image is rotated. But these width and heights didn't return the same dimensions that the `GD`-functions `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` returned after the image was rotated. I've tried out several of calculations using `sin()` and `cos()` for retrieving the width and height but still didn't get exact same values as `imagesx()` and `imagesy()`.

That got me thinking... What if I change my approach to:

1. Set the relation/ratio between "scaled down image" and original image.
2. Do the actual image-rotation
3. Apply the new dimensions based on the ratio multiplied with `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` - values return after the rotation

New code:

```
//Rotate resized image (if it should be)
$angle = $ps['product_angle'];
if (intval($angle) <> 0) {

    //Get current dimensions from file
    $current_source_x = imagesx($source_image);
    $current_source_y = imagesy($source_image);

    //Get current ratio of "scaled down image"
    $ratio_x = $ps['product_width'] / $current_source_x;
    $ratio_y = $ps['product_height'] / $current_source_y;

    //Rotate image
    $source_image = imagerotate($source_image, 360-$angle, imageColorAllocateAlpha($source_image, 255, 255, 255, 127));    

    //Now we get a new width from the imagerotate()-function, use those to set new_width from
    //ratio/propoprtions is used from origin width and height
    $ps['product_width']  = imagesx($source_image) * $ratio_x;
    $ps['product_height'] = imagesy($source_image) * $ratio_y;

}
```

This worked fine - almost... the issue now was that the if the rotated image's new width and/or height got larger then the origin dimensions of the image, then the proportions wouldn't be accurate (and would cut off the imagesometimes (depending the rotation angle)).

The code was modified so heights and widths would be in proportion to the image from the file when creating the resized image.

```
//Rotate resized image (if it should be)
$angle = $ps['product_angle'];
if (intval($angle) <> 0) {

    //Get current dimensions from file
    $current_source_x = imagesx($source_image);
    $current_source_y = imagesy($source_image);

    //Get current ratio of "scaled down image"
    $ratio_x = $ps['product_width'] / $current_source_x;
    $ratio_y = $ps['product_height'] / $current_source_y;

    //Rotate image
    $source_image = imagerotate($source_image, 360-$angle, imageColorAllocateAlpha($source_image, 255, 255, 255, 127));    

    //Now we get a new width from the imagerotate()-function, use those to set new_width from
    //ratio/propoprtions is used from origin width and height
    $ps['product_width']  = imagesx($source_image) * $ratio_x;
    $ps['product_height'] = imagesy($source_image) * $ratio_y;

    //Set these so we can modifiy the width and height given from getimagesize()-function below
    $ps['source_width'] = imagesx($source_image) ;
    $ps['source_height'] =  imagesy($source_image);            
}


//If image is rotated, then width and height are adjusted with these values
if (isset($ps['source_width']) && isset($ps['source_height']) ) {
    $source_width = $ps['source_width'];
    $source_height = $ps['source_height'];                                    
}

//Set position where to place in the image to save
$dest_x = $ps['product_left'];
$dest_y = $ps['product_top'];

$dest_width = (int)$ps['product_width'];
$dest_height = (int)$ps['product_height'];

//Resize source-image to new width and height and then copy from source to destination point
imagecopyresized($dest_image, $ps['source_image'], $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $dest_width, $dest_height, $source_width, $source_height);
```

So my final solution would include these steps:

1. Set the relation/ratio between "scaled down image" and original image.
2. Do the actual image-rotation
3. Apply the new dimensions based on the ratio multiplied with `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` - values return after the rotation
4. Set **"fake"** width and height when image has been rotated, so the resizing would work in proportion to the original image.

I hope this would help anyone who's struggling with the same issue I've struggled with (a few hours to much)!